# "babel" is read-only with react jsx

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am importing babel to my jsx file like below. But i get error for Module build failed: SyntaxError: "babel" is read-only

```
var babel = require("babel-core");
import { transform } from 'babel-core';
import * as babel from 'babel-core';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is because you are using same variable name **babel**.

```
var babel = require("babel-core");
import * as babel from 'babel-core';
```

Use different names and try again.

Comment: To be fair, the OP is using the code from https://babeljs.io/docs/core-packages.  It's not 100% clear how to do this, I don't think.